# How can I add a custom color to a gradient with Tailwind and React?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Here's my tailwind.config.js:

```js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
    purge: {
        content: ['./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
    },
    theme: {
        colors: {
            'BASE_YELLOW': '#C9FB5C',
            'black': '000',
        },
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: [],
}
```

And my React component div:

```js
<div className="w-full min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gradient-to-r from-colors.BASE_YELLOW to-colors.black ...">
```

But the screen is just grey. How do I use these colors in a gradient?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you meant to override all Tailwind colors, [extending the defaults](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#extending-the-defaults) instead works best.

```
module.exports = {
 purge: {
  content: ['./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
 },
 theme: {
  extend: {
   colors: {
    'BASE_YELLOW': '#C9FB5C',
     'black': '000',
   }
  }
 },
 variants: {},
 plugins: [],
}
```

When using your colors, you don't need to add the `colors` key to the name.

```
<div className="w-full min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gradient-to-r from-BASE_YELLOW to-black ...">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **linear-gradients** ([documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#linear-gradients))

```
<div className="bg-gradient-to-r from-[#ffedd5] to-[red]">
```

Comment: what about degrees please?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use separated layer custom class.

```
.from-my-color {
  --tw-gradient-from: #1c90f7 var(--tw-gradient-from-position);
}
```

and then use them in className.

```
<div className"bg-gradient-to-r from-my-color to-my-color" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In the theme object inside the extend object add **backgroundImage** object with the gradient you want using css

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
    purge: {
        content: ['./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
    },
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                'BASE_YELLOW': '#C9FB5C',
                'black': '000',
            },
            backgroundImage: {
                'my-gradient': 'linear-gradient(102deg, rgba(3, 5, 29, 0.85) 2.11%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.85) 100%)',
            }
        }
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: [],
}
```

you can then use this class in you project

```
<div className="my-gradient p-4 m-4">
     {/* More JSX */}
</div>
```

Note: In the tailwind config file adding custom classes or properties in the theme object directly will override all the defaults in the which can be helpful if you want to enforce the styling

Answer (score 0):

[You can use any arbitrary color values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gradient-color-stops#arbitrary-values).

You can use hex values:

```html
<div className="bg-gradient-to-r from-[#ffedd5] to-[red]">
```

Or you can use rgb values:

```html
<div className="bg-gradient-to-r from-[rgba(6,6,6,0.00008)] to-[rgba(0,0,0,0.8)]">
```

Note: When using rgb(a) values there cannot be any whitespaces in the value. `rgba(6, 6, 6, 0.8)` will not work.

See the Tailwind [docs](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode) for more info on using arbitrary values (JIT mode).